# How do I use Entity Framework in Code First Drop-Create mode?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I'm using Entity Framework v4.  I have followed the instructions in the [Nerd Dinner tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx).  I'm currently in development mode (not released to any higher environments) and would like for tables to be recreated on each new deployment, since the models are still highly volatile and I don't care to retain data.  However, this does not occur.  Tables are not created/modified, or anything happening to the DB.  If I move to a migrations model by using the Package Manager commands: enable-migrations, add-migration (initial), this works and uses my migrations.  However, since I don't yet want to have granular migrations and only want my initial create script, I am forced to delete the migrations folder, redo the commands (enable-migrations, add-migration) and delete the database manually, every time I change anything.

How do I get the drop/create behavior of code first to occur?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use [DropCreateDatabaseAlways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506(v=vs.103).aspx) initializer for your database. It will always recreate database during first usage of context in app domain:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourContextName>());
```

Actually if you want to seed your database, then create your own initializer, which will be inherited from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`:

```
public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourContextName>
{
     protected override void Seed(MagnateContext context)
     {
         // seed database here
     }
}
```

And set it before first usage of context

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
```

Comment: @RyanLangton @lazyberezovsky you can make it occur immediately if you place this straight after your call to SetInitializer(): `Database.Initialize(false);`

Answer (score 0):

If the database already exists and you want to make changes to your model, you use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContextName>`