# Dropping table In Entity Framework Core and UWP

Tags: entity-framework, uwp, code-first

I am learning Entity Framework with UWP. I tried dropping a table by deleting it from DbContext. When running the code after migration I received an error that dropping primary key is not supported with UWP.
This article, https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/sqlite/limitations.html, recommends using sql(string) method.
This article, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx, has an example I am trying to follow.

```
   using (var context = new BloggingContext())
        {
            var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList();
        }
```

I cant find the reference.
I like the idea of using sql statements.
In another stackoverflow article, [How to drop a table in Entity Framework Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472356/how-to-drop-a-table-in-entity-framework-code-first), I don't understand: " write the DropTable statement in the Down method of [DateStamp]_InitialCreate.cs class and the table will be dropped". Isit relevant to my problem. If so how do I implement it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried dropping a table by deleting it from DbContext.

You can use `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` to drop tables:

```
//you have to use this namespace
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
     db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DROP TABLE [Blogs]");
}
```

> I don't understand: " write the DropTable statement in the Down method of [DateStamp]_InitialCreate.cs class

`<DateStamp>_<MigrationName>.cs` is generated through your migration(Add-Migration MigrationName). You can find it under Migrations folder. And inside this class file you can find Down Method.

Everytime you call `db.Database.Migrate()` (normally in `App.xaml.cs` file). SQLite will check the table `__EFMigrationsHistory` to see if the `<DateStamp>_<MigrationName>.cs` file has been executed. You can modify the timestamp of `[Migration("<TimeStamp>_<MigrationName>")]` in following file to manually execute the migration again:

[image]

And also, you can modify the codes inside to do a migration according to your requirement.