# Execute SQL command in Entity Framework Core 2.0 to delete all data in a table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to execute an SQL command from Entity Framework Core 2.0, but I can't figure out how to do so.

1.- The reason why I need to, is that I want to delete all data from a database table, and using `Context.remove` or `Context.removeRange` would produce many calls to DB (one for each data in the table).

2.- I've read that there is a method `.ExecuteSqlCommand` to accomplish that, but that method is not present in my Context.Database (maybe in Core 2.0 it was removed?). Here is the source of the info: [Dropping table In Entity Framework Core and UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674100/dropping-table-in-entity-framework-core-and-uwp)

So, basically I need to delete a table from code using EF Core 2.0 and, as far as I know, I need to execute a SQL command for that.

Thank you.

Here is my .csproj, just in case i'm missing something

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />    
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />    -->
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ensure that you reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to include all the necessary extension methods that would allow you to execute raw SQL commands.

From the source repository I found `ExecuteSqlCommand` and related extension methods

```
int count = await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("DELETE FROM [Blogs]");
```

Found an article that suggested using ADO.Net.

First you grab a connection from the context, create a command and execute that.

```
using (var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection()) {
    await connection.OpenAsync();     
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [Blogs]";
        var result = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: That reference is not enough. You need to also reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` which is where `ExecuteSqlCommand[Async]` is defined.

Comment: In EF Core 3.1 us should not wrap `var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection();` in a `using` block. When you do that, the connection of the context is disposed and trying to use it afterward will give this error: `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.`.

Answer (score 22):

For EF Core 3.x, use this namespace and this code :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; 
...
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

Comment: ExecuteSqlRaw doesn't seem to exist in 3.1.

Comment: You are required to add in the nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational to gain access to the ExecuteSqlRaw command.

Answer (score 7):

This will perform over any of delete row-per-row from table methods.

```
context.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [" + tableName + "]");
```

> TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to the DELETE statement with no WHERE
>   clause; however, TRUNCATE TABLE is faster and uses fewer system and
>   transaction log resources.

[ExecuteStoreCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

[TRUNCATE TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql)

Answer (score 5):

@Nkosi is correct but since EF Core 3.x you should use `ExecuteSqlRaw` like @KevinDimey says.

Addition to the answer of @KevinDimey is the obsolete messages:

ExecuteSqlCommand:

> For the execution of SQL queries using plain strings, use
> ExecuteSqlRaw instead. For the execution of SQL queries using
> interpolated string syntax to create parameters, use
> ExecuteSqlInterpolated instead.

ExecuteSqlCommandAsync:

> For the async execution of SQL queries using plain strings, use
> ExecuteSqlRawAsync instead. For the async execution of SQL queries
> using interpolated string syntax to create parameters, use
> ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync instead.

Methods to use:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DELETE FROM [Blogs]");

await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("DELETE FROM [Blogs]");
```

Answer (score 4):

`Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` and `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` are available in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` namespace. Make sure you have it's reference.

Then it will be available in your class and you can call it like below,

```
Context.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE YOURTABLENAME");
```

Answer (score -4):

You can try this

```
 context.Patients.ToList().ForEach(v => v.ChangeTracker.State = ObjectState.Deleted);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: wasn't me, but i think that because your solution would generate multiple querys to delete all data, one for each entity with ObjectState.Deleted. Appart of this, your answer answers how to delete all data but not how to execute an SQL command from EF Core.

Comment: I didn't down vote and yes this would 'work'. But I'll tell you from experience that if you have a large list of patients to delete, this can take forever to execute. Executing a bulk delete using sql performs much better.

Comment: you have to delete the ".Tolist()" , you are fetching all the patients before deleting