# EF Core - Delete database tables in a schema at runtime

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API configures with EF Core and using SQL Server. I have a controller which adds tables to the database on post, and should delete those tables from the database on delete. The tables that are added will be added in a separate schema.

How can I delete the tables in the newly created schema at runtime?

This is the code to generate the tables:

```
RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator = 
    (RelationalDatabaseCreator) context.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
databaseCreator.CreateTables();
```

And how the schema name is applied to the context:

```
public DbSet<CustomEntity> CustomEntities { get;set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new EntityConfiguration<CustomEntity>(nameof(CustomEntities), schemaName));
}
```

The `EntityConfiguration` class:

```
public class EntityConfiguration<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly string tableName;
    private readonly string schema;

    public EntityConfiguration(string tableName, string schema)
    {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(schema))
        {
            builder.ToTable(tableName, schema);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework has no functionality to directly manage the schema as its designed for CRUD on the data level. You can use raw SQL commands to achieve this however, as of right now, EF Core does not have the ability to do this out of the box (it can only serialise a query using `FromSql()`). If you are determined to still do this in EF Core then this post might be of use: [Execute SQL command in Entity Framework Core 2.0 to delete all data in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114711/execute-sql-command-in-entity-framework-core-2-0-to-delete-all-data-in-a-table)

```
USING [Database-Name]
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DROP TABLE ?'
GO
```

You may have to drop foreign keys and other constraints before hand.