# How to create a event on time with EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to create a Event at a timestamp to delete a entry from a database in c# with EntityFrameworkCore. The plan is that I create a entry with a until date. If this date is reached the database should set the bool Elapsed to false.

**Punishment.cs**

```cs
    public class Punishment : Entity
    {
        public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime Until { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public bool Elapsed = false;
    }
```

I need something like in c#

```sql
CREATE EVENT userXYZUnban
ON SHEDULE AT [until timestamp]
DO UPDATE Punishment SET Elapsed = true WHERE CURDATE() > [until timestamp]
```

Comment: You can execute SQL query, see this other question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46115196/2703673

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support MySQL's create event. You can use something like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to execute code as frequently as needed. That code could use EF Core to apply the check and change you mention. You can also execute on a timer with IHostedService [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) without the overhead of Hangfire.

Comment: You're not really asking a question. "I need something like...", what keeps you from doing it?