# Reconstruct Database after Unit Test with EF6

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I want to delete the existing database and recreate it before or after the test are done.  Is this even possible ?

I do see some properties in the context obj for deleting and createifnotexist but i am not sure how and where to put it.

Comment: Checkout this question [This is how to do it][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162734/how-do-i-use-entity-framework-in-code-first-drop-create-mode

Answer (score 1):

Create a database initialiser which always drops and creates the database, populating it with seed data each time.  Use that initialiser only in your unit test class.

Or better still, don't unit test EF, you don't gain anything.  Mock your EF back end and only test your own code.

Answer (score 0):

if you store you database as a file (mdb) you can just restore the original file.

otherwhite you could write the code that creates and populates it in you testinitialize method

look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx for a place to get started